# jsessionID not kept between jmeter http requests

Tags: jmeter, jsessionid, cookiemanager

I'm trying to do a simple load-test in a website which requires you to log in first.

I read the jmeter documentation about the cookie manager and looks like as long as I make all my requests within the same thread group where the cookie manager is the sessionID is shared among the http requests but is not my case.

The simple structure I have is:

```
Thread Group
    HTTP Cookie Manager
    HTTP Requests Defaults
    Simple Controller
        http request  // POST method to authenticate in the site (this works fine, I get a session id)
        http request  // GET method (this one should use the same session id from the previous http requests but I get a new one instead)
```

I did this same web page flow in firefox using firebug to see the requests/responses and the session id is the same, the server doesn't send a new one so looks like the cookie manager is not keeping the same session id and using it for all the requests.

Can someone point me in the right direction? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check the get request sends the same jsessionid cookie in the request as the one returned in previous response.

If it's the case then check your login was fine, as it is probably root cause of issue

Comment: Actually that is the problem the login works fine ( I can tell because of the response I get) but then the next request (GET) sets another cookie, doesn't uses the same one from the login

Comment: Show requests and response tabs for the 2 samplers